# Install Rational Team Concert & Rational Insight

Tags: ibm-jazz

I need to install both RTC and Rational Insight in my local machine but I am confuse that should I install Data base first for it. Even i don't know which database is right with Insight & RTC.

I don't know how to set up Dataware House?

Answer (score 2):

The choice of database is important when combining RTC and Insight. With RTC by itself, especially with a small team, you can use Derby (included) for both the repository database (basically, the operational database for the product) and for the data warehouse (a separate database used for reporting). However, if you want to use Rational Insight, or RRDI (both of which include Cognos-based reporting), your must have a data warehouse on a database other than Derby. Typically, Oracle, SQL Server and DB2 are your choices, but please consult the platform requirements list for your version of Rational Insight to ensure you're using a supported configuration.

Regarding setting up the data warehouse, if you're using RTC with Insight, often you will share a warehouse between the two applications (that is, RTC can use the warehouse for its internal BIRT-based reporting, and Insight can use the warehouse for its Cognos-based reporting). In that case, you would set up the data warehouse as part of your RTC setup (the JTS setup wizard configures the data warehouse), and then point Insight at that warehouse when you set Insight up.

I hope this helps.

James

Technical Lead, IBM Rational Reporting